# remove always last array in php

Tags: php

i am trying to remove last array after i made an explode on this strings:
Example 1

```
Adress1
Adress2
String1 : String2
```

Example 2

```
Adress1
Adress2
Adress3
String1 : String2
```

My idea was first to check if their is a match " : " in string(adrori) then the last array "String1 : String2" should be removed completely. No matther how much array counts would be counted.

Here is my code:

```
if (preg_match("/ : /", $adrori)) {
    $arr2 = explode("\n", $adrori);
    $adrori = array_pop($arr2);
    $adrori = implode("\n", $adrori);
}
```

thanks

Comment: give an example, its hard to follow.

Comment: I don't understand the examples. Can you please post the output for `var_export($adrori);` that corresponds to the examples?

Comment: Do you know that if the string contains “String1 : String2” in first line and “Adress3” in the last line, “Adress3” will be removed?

Comment: all addresses ends with String : String. Sometimes are two rows and sometimes more than two. But always appears at the end of String the following: ExampleString : ExampleString. So i am trying to remove always the last row with " : " at the end of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_pop` changes its argument and returns the last element. So you should do it like this.

```
if (preg_match("/ : /", $adrori)) {
    $arr2 = explode("\n", $adrori);
    array_pop($arr2);
    $adrori = implode("\n", $arr2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, after removing last array item you re-implode it.

So, you can obtain desired result also using `preg_replace`, without exploding/imploding:

```
$adrori = trim( preg_replace( '/.+ : .+$/', '', $adrori ) );
```

or:

```
$adrori = preg_replace( '/\n.+ : .+$/', '', $adrori );
```

Pattern explanation:

```
\n  newline
.+  one or more characters
 :  space-colon-space
.+  one or more characters
$   end of string
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$a = array('a1','a:2');
$b = array_filter($a,function($value){
if(strpos($value, ':') === false){
  return $value;
 }
});
print_r($b);
```

Answer (score 0):

the example from @ksimka worked! Thank you so much people!

My mistake was to give variable to aray_pop.

Wrong:

```
 if (preg_match("/ : /", $adrori)) {
        $arr2 = explode("\n", $adrori);
        $adrori = array_pop($arr2);
        $adrori = implode("\n", $adrori);
    }
```

right:

```
 if (preg_match("/ : /", $adrori)) {
        $arr2 = explode("\n", $adrori);
        array_pop($arr2);
        $adrori = implode("\n", $adrori);
    }
```

Thank you